# Case statement inside a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Transform.usp_CustomerInfo
AS
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE [Transform].[CustomerInfo]

    INSERT INTO [Transform].[CustomerInfo] (CustomerName, Total, AvgPurchaseTime, StoreName)
        SELECT
            CASE
               WHEN C.LastName = NULL THEN C.FirstName
               ELSE (C.LastName + ', ' + C.FirstName)
            END AS 'Name', 
            SUM(T.Total),
            D.FullDate,
            UPPER(C.StoreName) AS 'Store Name'
        FROM 
            [Extract].[DimTransaction] AS T
        JOIN 
            [Extract].[DimCustomer] AS C ON T.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
        JOIN 
            [Extract].[DimState] AS S ON C.StateID = S.StateID
        JOIN 
            [Extract].[DimDateTime] AS D ON D.DateTimeID = T.TransactionID
        GROUP BY 
            C.LastName, C.FirstName, D.FullDate, C.StoreName
        ORDER BY 
            Convert(date, D.FullDate, 101) ASC
```

I am trying to get it where if the Last Name comes up NULL to only use the first name else I want to concatenate Last Name and First Name

Comment: Nothing ever `equals NULL`.  And nothing ever `does not equal NULL` either.  You need to use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: May be you could try `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
(CASE WHEN C.LastName IS NULL THEN C.FirstName
      ELSE (C.LastName + ', ' + C.FirstName)
 END) AS Name,
```

Or just use `COALESCE()`:

```
(COALESE(C.LastName + ', ', '') + C.FirstName) as Name
```

Comment: Thank You, I should have known better with the = sign, sometimes C# likes to creep in.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is not a value, so it can't use =,<,> to compare with other value.
BTW, your case when statement also can do with ISNULL

```
ISNULL(C.LastName + ', ','')+c.FirstName AS Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check as = NULL but you can check the default value instead, in the following way or you have to in the way that others suggested:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(c.lastName,'') = '' THEN 
    -------
ELSE
    -------
END
```

IF you are using *SQLSERVER2008+* then you can use CONCAT as well:

```
CONCAT(ISNULL(c.lastname + ', ',''), c.firstname) as Name
```